# Where to start programming with Kinect or Asus Xtion Pro in ROS?

Tags: kinect, openni, pcl, ros-fuerte, xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My problem is I need to use Xtion Pro live to get gesture data on ROS fuerte.

What would you suggest me to try?

1. PCL is powerful blah, but I am very confused when it comes to understand PCL tutorials, as if they are meant to be used directly, instead of making an example to programmers. Besides, how to convert PCl tutorial to ROS environment is a bit unknown, even after following ROS PCL tutorial.
2. ROS supports OPENNI. Though, I could not see any example on "how". Besides, sources on programming with OPENNI is a bit limited. Does anyone know a good source or where to start.
3. There is a very very good book on programming in SimpleOpenNI. Though, examples are coded in Java. Does ROS support Java? I assume it does, but does it also support SimpleOPenNI as well? How?

Actually I have seen many questions regarding this Kinect-Ros-Openni-PCL issue.Though I did not see a clear answer. I wish there was a good tutorial on those. If someone could answer, I am sure you will not me only helping me. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71947/where-to-start-programming-with-kinect-or-asus-xtion-pro-in-ros?/) by [mary](https://answers.ros.org/users/5710/mary/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

as far as i know, the pure pcl library has different kinect driver with ros.
so using pcl_ros package is the best choice if you try to use ros. You may examine the the perception_pcl, inside which there are some basic functionalities like filters and segmentation, though it will not be powerful as the orginial pcl libraray.

for how to get started with pcl in ros, you may refer to http://correll.cs.colorado.edu/?p=2807, which may help

---

Originally posted by [ljk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5470/ljk/) with karma: 155 on 2013-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0